Detect and ignore anomalous number in MySQL MIN/MAX query
I am trying to find the MIN and MAX of a simple data set....
Score
15
12
8
28
5

Simply doing this would work.
SELECT MIN(Score) AS minScore, MAX(Score) AS maxScore FROM Scores;

Which should return 5 and 28.
But what if somehow a huge number ended up in the set throwing off the results...
Score
15
120000
8
28
5

This would return 5 and 120000.
What I need to do is to somehow have the query detect the unusually large number and ignore it in the result returning 5 and 28.
The actual data would have a large number of rows, and the range is unknown, but the anomaly should stand out. Was hoping for some sort of mathematical way to omit the anomaly.
Unfortunately, I cannot use a subquery for efficiency reasons. The final query is a bit system intensive so need to do it in one pass.

How do you define an anomalous number?

What if you have 2 extreme numbers, like 15, 12000, 8, 28, 5, 13000, should they both be ignored?

It seems like you should do this with statistical analysis software processing the query results, rather than doing it in SQL.

What similar question do you talk about? Anyway, your question is absolutely meaningless as long as you don't provide an exact definition/range which numbers should be excluded. We can't do that for you. Another question: Why can't you use a subquery?

What's an "unusually large number"? Are you looking into the standard deviation, variance, confidence interval, or another statistical concept?

Here is one method to identify outliers in data https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/interquartile-range/ check if this logic is suitable. Let us know if you have difficulty implementing it in SQL

Maybe check it against STDEV for outliers?

I don't think this is a programming problem ,therefore off topic, until OP has decided on a method but can't implement it

I never said it was a programming question, it is a SQL question.

Jeez, you guys (@JonasMetzler, Mr. "Impaler"), lighten up. No need to bombard OP with questions intended to show their ignorance.

@Robert Thanks for calling that out. Hadn't been on in a while, was hoping the negativity had stopped here. Guess not :(

@RobertDodier No, my intention is not at all to bombard someone with stupid question or to cast a slur at them. Note it's very unkind that you blame that. The question is unclear and could certainly be improved, then both OP and people with similar questions and also people who might provide a solution could benefit much.

@JonasMetzler If that's not your intention, then my advice to you is to reread stuff before posting and try to imagine you're another person reading the stuff you wrote. If the question is unclear, there are other ways to express that.

Someone closed this for being unclear, not really sure how this could have been clearer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

ihatzi, the bad news is that outlier or anomaly detection is not entirely straightforward, and it hinges on exactly what you expect normal and abnormal numbers to look like. My advice is to take a look at [stats.SE] to get some ideas about that, and then revisit the problem of how to implement any particular outlier filtering scheme in SQL.

One option to exclude the scores that are considered to be anomaly is to calculate the percentage of the anomaly beeing bigger than average ...
If there are some border intermediate scores ( 2400, 620 ) then you should decide to include them or not by adjusting the percentage condition ...
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
WITH
    tbl ( score ) As
      ( Select 15 Union All 
        Select 12 Union All 
        Select  8 Union All 
        Select 28 Union All
        Select 12000 Union All 
        Select 2400 Union All
        Select 620 Union All
        Select  5 
      )

... calculate what is the percentage of how much the current score is bigger than average
The results will depend on the size of anomaly and you should decide what is the margin when the score is too big to be taken into account.
Select tbl.*, 
       ( score - Avg(score) Over() ) * 100 / Avg(score) Over() as pct_over_avg
From tbl  




score
pct_over_avg




15
-99.20466596


12
-99.36373277


8
-99.57582185


28
-98.51537646


12000
536.26723224


2400
27.25344645


620
-67.12619300


5
-99.73488865



The bigger the anomaly the narrower percentage to be selected. Expected it to be less than -95% for rows that should be included.
Use the above code as subquery (why not) and put the condition in Where clause that fits your actual data...
--       S Q L :  
Select    Max(t.score) as max_score, Min(t.score) as min_score
From      ( Select tbl.*, 
                   ( score - Avg(score) Over() ) * 100 / Avg(score) Over() as pct_over_avg
            From tbl 
          ) t
Where     t.pct_over_avg < -95

R e s u l t :



max_score
min_score




28
5



... if you change the Where condition value -95 to -65 then you'll get max_score 620 ...
fiddle
